# Error when trying to read a CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a telecom dataset CSV file that I have on my PC using the code line

```
telecomDataframe <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\rhous\\Downloads\\C:\\Users\\rhous\\Downloads\\customer_churn_analysis-master\\WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv",header=TRUE)
```

But I am getting the below error in R

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>   hous\Downloads\C:\Users\rhous\Downloads\customer_churn_analysis-master\WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv': Invalid argument

Can anyone spot the error?
I've tried adding double backslash `\\` but still getting the two errors.

Comment: The one obvious prob is that use of `C:\\` twice. You might not be having path correct.

Comment: if you are only loading one file you might want to try and swap the long path with a prompt selection. instead of typing the path use the `file.choose()` function with no arguments and just select your .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your file path

```
telecomDataframe <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\rhous\\Downloads\\customer_churn_analysis-master\\WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks i have fixed the typo on the path , initially i did a copy paste on the path twice thus the error

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your path:

> `C:\\Users\\rhous\\Downloads\\C:\\Users\\rhous\\Downloads\\customer_churn_analysis-master\\WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command.

telecomDataframe <- read.csv(file="C:\Users\rhous\Downloads\customer_churn_analysis-master\WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv",header=TRUE)

Comment: Can you describe what you've changed and why? Shared knowledge is great knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can choose the CSV file.

```
filename <- file.choose()
data <- read.csv(filename, skip=1)
name <- basename(filename)
```

Or, hard-code the path.

```
# Read CSV into R
MyData <- read.csv(file="c:/your_path_here/Data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```